# Log Shipping breaking daily on SQL Server 2005

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, log-shipping

I am facing a somewhat serious problem with Log Shipping on SQL Server 2005 and I am having trouble to correct it, so I will try some help from SF's experts.

- I have a Windows 2003 Server (**PROD**) that ships transactional log backups to another two servers:

  - **STAND1**: Windows 2003 Server with SQL Server 2005.
  - **STAND2**: Windows 2008 R2 Server with SQL Server 2005.
- The problem is that Log Shipping to **STAND2** is breaking for ~ 90 minutes some times of the day and returning back without intervention. The breaking occur at times when the backup file is larger (after reindexing, etc). I can see the message below logged on the COPY job:

`*** Error: The specified network name is no longer available`

The copy agent was breaking dozens times a day only to **STAND2** server, and after the changes below "only" breaks ~ two times a day:

- The frequency of the backup job was changed from 5 minutes to 10 minutes.
- Instead of backing up the 4 databases to the same folder, the log backups are now saved on separated folders for each database.
- The backup job doesn't run 24hs now, and only for 14 hours a day, when people are working on the database.
- I configured the SQL Server instances on the three servers to limit the memory, leaving more memory to the OS.

Now I don't know what to do. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the network link between two servers by copying a medium size backup file manually.
Then compare the results with the log shipping copy job. Some time the copy job is not fast enough to copy all Trn backups in timely manner. I mean some time the copy is not finished before the alert time set up(normally 45 Mins)

Comment: Hello! I've tried to copy a big backup file (~12GB) with rocobopy from **PROD** to **STAND2** and the process is aborted in the middle with the same error reported by the SQL Server Log Shipping COPY agent. The problem does *not* occur when I copy a big file from another server to **PROD2**!

Comment: Seems like both server tried to access same backup file to copy at same time. Anyway *** Error: The specified network name is no longer available *** means some thing wrong with network as the file is unavailable and \or some process delete that file.How long the tlog files stays on drive after copy finish.

Comment: Hello! The tlogs backup files stay for 72 hours.

Comment: We are suspecting that there is some problem with the switch, because we copied a large backup file from other two servers (STAND1 and other), and Log Shipping from PROD to STAND2 break until the copy finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you say after Index rebuild job. Is it during business hours ?

As per error you mention It seems like sometime there is network glitch causes copy job to fail.

Comment: Hello! The index rebuild is done off hours (at midnight).